# How to import libs module in different files

Tags: module, rust

I have troubles resolving my module imports. Here is my file structure:

```
.
|-- scenes
|   |-- libs
|   |    |-- mod.rs
|   |    `-- components.rs
|   |-- mod.rs
|   `-- scene.rs
`-- main.rs
```

I can't import the module `libs` in scene.rs. I think I don't get it the module logical. Any help would be very appreciable.

if I try to do `mod libs;` in scene.rs

```
error[E0583]: file not found for module `libs`
 --> src/scenes/scene.rs:2:5
  |
2 | mod libs;
  |     ^^^^
  |
  = help: name the file either scene/libs.rs or scene/libs/mod.rs inside the directory "src/scenes"
```

Contents files:

main.rs

```
mod scenes;
let sc = scenes::scene::Scene{};
```

scenes/scene.rs

```
mod libs; // errors
pub struct Sphere {
    pub center: libs::components::Point
}
pub struct Scene {}
```

scenes/mod.rs

```
pub mod scene;
pub mod libs;
```

scenes/libs/components.rs

```
pub struct Point {}
```

scenes/libs/mod.rs

```
pub mod components;
```

Comment: What happens when you try what the compiler suggests: *name the file either scene/libs.rs or scene/libs/mod.rs inside the directory "src/scenes"*?

Comment: I think you have done a mistake somewhere.

Comment: I completed with the content of files. I didn;t know  Rust-specific MCVE tips.
I can't try scene/libs.rs or scene/libs/mod.rs cause scene is a file. Or I miss something

Comment: nop sorry typo mistake, I edited my question.

Comment: *cause scene is a file* — scene *.rs* is a file — where is a file called only *scene*?

Comment: nowhere I thought to scene.rs effectively. If I tried to do **scene/libs.rs or scene/libs/mod.rs** It seems to offset the problem... I really don't feel like I'm doing anything complicated but I am pretty sure to miss dumb something.  The logic and file structure is pretty classic.

Comment: So, if you follow the error message, the error goes away and the code works? Sounds like there's no problem anymore and thus no question remaining.

Comment: No the error still there. But I found a trick, if I move all my code in mod.rs of each package and delete scene.rs and components.rs, the module resolution is correct.
I will read again and again the *book*. 
Thanks, even if I don't understand why my previous case is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `mod libs`, write `use crate::scenes::libs`.

The Rust 2018 Edition has changed the module system slightly to help clarify situations such as this.

Your directory should be restructured like so:

```
main.rs
scenes.rs
scenes
|   libs.rs
|   libs
|   |   components.rs
|   scene.rs
```

The main difference here is that `mod.rs` files are now extracted from their folder and named appropriately.

**PRE-RUST-2018 - NOV 2018**

Instead of `mod libs`, write `use scenes::libs`.

The error message is telling you is you're trying to declare the existence of a submodule of `scene` that does not exist. Instead, you want to import (with `use`) the `libs` module which is accessed by `scenes::libs` from the crate root.